# Installing imap-ssl extension on Wampserver 2.2

Tags: php, ssl, wamp, imap, php-extension

I am looking for a way to connect my IMAP-SSL GMail account using PHP, because I want to automate it.

I am following [this tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap) but it does not explain how to install imap-ssl extension on Wampserver.

Is there a simple (or at least clear) way to install imap-ssl extension on Wamp?

Comment: I found a way. Inspired by David Walsh's tutorial : http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap
But, it does NOT work with GMail. Any other seems to be fine. I work with a Microsoft Exchange mail.

`<?php

$inbox= imap_open("{xxxxxx.net:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "aaa@bbb.fr", "password");

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

var_dump($emails);

imap_close($inbox);

?>`

Comment: Don't add things like `[solved]` to your question's title, and don't put answers in the comments. You need to post your answer *as an answer*, below, and then accept it to mark this question as "solved".